# How to limit Jenkins child processes?

Tags: java, performance, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have clean installation of Jenkins CI on my UbuntuServer 12.10, no jobs, no nothing, just Jenkins. Installation is from aptitude. What thrills me is that Jenkins is doing nothing at the moment and has something about 40 child processes, which consumes quite a lot of my server's memory. Is there a way to limit number of these child processes to, for example, 10?

Comment: I think it is not processes, but threads. Usually web app has a thread pool for incoming requests. Maybe the default size is large. Do you know which web-server is used to run the jenkins in Ubuntu?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245093/change-number-of-threads-for-jenkins-server

Comment: How much memory is it using? How did you check this? Can you use VisualVM to see how much memory is being used by Java?

Comment: You should add a copy-paste showing these 40 processes of yours.

Comment: @kan You are probably right, these are threads, not processes. I have no idea which webserver it runs at in Ubuntu. Is there any way to limit number of these threads?

Comment: @pawel.kalisz So, does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245093/change-number-of-threads-for-jenkins-server

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Specify number of executers corresponding to the text box "# of executors"

Another best method is using slave machines to divide work load. Use master slave configuration to setup slave machines.