# "Insufficient memory" on Jenkins server startup

Tags: java, memory, jenkins, jvm, jetty

First time user of Jenkins here, and having a bit of trouble getting it started.  From the Linux shell I run a command like:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -jar jenkins.war
```

and consistently get an error like:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# pthread_getattr_np
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/twilliams/.jenkins/hs_err_pid36290.log
```

First, the basics:

- Jenkins 1.631
- Running via the jetty embedded in the war file
- OpenJDK 1.7.0_51
- Oracle Linux (3.8.13-55.1.5.el6uek.x86_64)
- 386 GB ram
- 40 cores

I get the same problem with a number of other configurations as well: using Java Hotspot 1.8.0_60, running through Apache Tomcat, and using all sorts of different values for `-Xms/-Xmx/-Xss` and similar options.

I've done a fair bit of research and *think* I know what the problem is, but am at a loss as how to solve it.  I suspect that I'm running into the virtual memory overcommit issue mentioned [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F317115%2Fjenkins-ci-cannot-allocate-memory&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEBmGNQngQn08Vn1BXnEq71girpHw); the relevant bits from ulimit:

```
--($:)-- ulimit -a
...
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 8388608
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 8388608
...
```

If I double the virtual memory limit as root, I can start Jenkins, but I'd rather not run Jenkins as the root user.

Another workaround: a soon-to-be-decommissioned machine with 48 GB ram and 24 cores can start Jenkins without issue, though (I suspect) just barely: according to htop, its virtual memory footprint is just over 8 GB.  I suspect, as a result, that the memory overcommit issue is scaling with the number of processors on the machine, presumably the result of Jenkins starting a number of threads proportional to the number of processors present on the host machine.  I roughly captured the thread count via `ps -eLf | grep jenkins | wc -l` and found that the thread count spikes at around 114 on the 40 core machine, and 84 on the 24 core machine.

Does this explanation seem sound?  Provided it does...

1. Is there any way to configure Jenkins to reduce the number of threads it spawns at startup?  I tried the arguments discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245093/change-number-of-threads-for-jenkins-server) but, as advertised, they didn't seem to have any effect.
2. Are there any VMs available that don't suffer from the overcommit issue, or some other configuration option to address it?

The sanest option at this point may be to just run Jenkins in a virtualized environment to limit the resources at its disposal to something reasonable, but at this point I'm interested in this problem on an intellectual level and want to know how to get this recalcitrant configuration to behave.

**Edit**

Here's a snippet from the hs_error.log file, which guided my initial investigation:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# pthread_getattr_np
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
```

Here are a couple of command lines I tried, all with the same result.

- Starting with a pitiful amount of heap space:

  - `java -Xms2m -Xmx2m -Xss228k -jar jenkins.war`
- Starting with significantly more heap space:

  - `java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Xss1m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -jar jenkins.war`
- Room to grow:

  - `java -Xms2m -Xmx1024m -Xss228k -jar jenkins.war`

A number of other configurations were tried as well.  Ultimately I don't think that the problem is heap exhaustion here - it's that the JVM is trying to reserve too much virtual memory for itself (in which to store the heap, thread stacks, etc) than allowed by the ulimit settings.  Presumably this is the result of the overcommit issue linked earlier, such that if Jenkins is spawning 120 threads, it's erroneously trying to reserve 120x as much VM space as the master process originally occupied.

Having done what I could with the other options suggested in that log, I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the thread count in Jenkins to test the thread VM overcommit theory.

**Edit #2**

Per Michał Grzejszczak, this is an issue with the glibc distributed with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 as discussed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7154).  The issue can be worked around via explicit setting of the environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`, in my case `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2`.  Without explicit setting of this variable, the JVM will apparently attempt to spawn (8 x cpu core count) threads, each consuming 64M.  My 40 core case would have required northward of 10 gigs of virtual ram, exceeding (by itself) the ulimit on my machine of 8 gigs.  Setting this to 2 reduces VM consumption to around 128 megs.

Comment: Not sure why your virtual memory footprint is 8GB in this case. I haver been using Jenkins successfully using heap size memory between 512MB to 1 GB

Comment: *"and using all sorts of different values for -Xms/-Xmx/-Xss and similar options."*, please provide an exhaustive list to see if you may have missed something. Also try [NMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) to see what reserves that address space. also consider simply restricting memory while raising the limit for virtual memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins memory footprint is related more to the number and size of projects it is managing than the number of CPUs or available memory. Jenkins should run fine on 1GB of heap memory unless you have gigantic projects on it.

You may have misconfigured the JVM though. -Xmx and -Xms parameters govern heap space JVM can use. -Xmx is a limit for heap memory, -Xms is a starting value for heap memory. Heap is a single memory area for entire JVM. You can easily monitor it by various tools like JConsole or VisualVM.

On the other hand -Xss is not related to heap. It is the size of a thread stack for all threads in this JVM process. As Java programs tend to create numerous threads setting this parameter too big can prevent your program from launching. Typically this value is in the range of 512**kb**. Entering here 512**m** instead makes it impossible for JVM to start. Make sure your settings do not contain any such mistakes (and post your memory config too).

Comment: I attached some additional information, including some of the Xmx, Xms, and Xss options used.  As mentioned, I don't _think_ heap exhaustion is the culprit here.

Comment: Is your OpenJDK 64 bit?

Comment: What is the number of executors in the config file? Try configuring 0. It is located in config.xml: <hudson>...<numExecutors>

Comment: I'm running 64 bit linux.  The output from java -version is `java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.0.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`   Config file didn't exist, but I was able to generate one on the older machine on which I was able to get Jenkins started and then copy it to the newer machine.  numExecutors was 2 initially.  Setting it to 0 didn't make any difference on the newer machine.  Looks like the directory holding the configuration here is `.jenkins`.

Comment: You are probably right about virtaul memory overcommit. I would ensure that UseCompressedOops is on for your JVM, however it should be by default (java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal). I have bigger apps running well below 8GB of virtual memory, so I am suprised that vanilla Jenkins uses more. Can you get an output from pmap on that other machine, or better yet on the bigger server before the error occurs? That would tell us what is taking so much space.

Comment: definitely using CompressedOops: `java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -jar jenkins.war | grep -i compressed` gives `bool UseCompressedOops                        := true            {lp64_product}`.  [Old](http://pastebin.com/EHww4YJP) and [new](http://pastebin.com/6wGfUSSu) pmap outputs.  The new output wasn't immediately before process death, but about as close as I could manage via the command `sleep 2.3 && pgrep -u twilliams -f jenkins | xargs pmap >/home/twilliams/pmap.new & java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -jar jenkins.war`.  About to take a crack at the pmap outputs myself.

Comment: Big difference I see is that there are 96 of the 65404K (threads?) on the new run vs 68 on the old run.  Not much there to identify what the objects are, though, or why there are 28 more of them on the new vs the old machine.  Also not sure how comparable the pre-startup state that the snapshot is captured for the new half is to the post-startup state of the old half.

Comment: These 96 entries are the problem. On my vanilla jenkins installation there are no such entries. Perhaps one of the plugins that you have configured is misbehaving a bit and allocating something unnecessarily. These might be threads with increased stack size. As long as you do not have virtual memory limit such behavior may be unnoticed. You can either attach JConsole or VisualVM to the old process and check what threads these might be, or turn off each suspect plugin in turn to see if it brings any changes in memory usage.

Comment: I haven't installed any plugins beyond what came with the default jenkins.war distributable.  I had updated them, but it made no difference.  Per your suggestion I disabled them, but ran into the same issue.  Here are updated pmaps for the [old](http://pastebin.com/kCJKG61S) and [new](http://pastebin.com/NunYP1G0) halves.  I'll check with JConsole or VisualVM tomorrow to see if I can get a better idea as to what these objects are.

Comment: I have found some bugs in HADOOP related to this: [MAPREDUCE-3065](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3065) and [HADOOP-7154](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7154). It seems that some new stuff in glibc is causing this. The solutions that I have found talk about tuning `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`. I'm not very knowledgeable about it, but suggest you try it.

Comment: From what I read setting `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4` will limit the number of 64MB pools to just 4 (default limit is 8 x cpu core count). HADOOP uses 4, Heroku, on the other hand, sugests 2.

Comment: That was the silver bullet.  `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2` and Jenkins started up without a hitch.  1,265,928K memory usage now according to pmap.  I'll update the question with the solution and accept your answer.  Thanks for all of your help!